# Good design for large growing table sql

Tags: sql, database, database-design

I have order table that contains,

```
Order table{
    order id, item id, date...
}
```

As time goes by, the table is going to grow infinitely large.

What is good practice when handling growing table?

I'm thinking create a sp to check query date, then create new table every day. It doesn't seem like a good solution.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Infinity is really big.  Databases handle millions and even billions of rows, so I wouldn't worry about such growth.

Comment: Agree with @GordonLinoff. There is no practical limit to the size of a table, and if you use indexes correctly then performance should not be an issue. An index on date would, for practical purposes, give you the same performance as splitting the table every day. If it ever gets really too big, then you may archive rows off by year or some other criteria. No-one in their right mind would do it by day.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are very accurate and correct: There is no reason to take care of such a table. 
If you work in some huge retail company and expect few thousands of orders per hour, then the solution is in hardware, not the DB. A high-end bare-metal server with multiple SSD disks in RAID 0 would allow to handle a table of 1 TB without sweating. 
In the DB, simple, common practices, like correct indexing, should suffice. The details depend on your DBMS: Different details apply to Oracle, than to mysql, than to MS-SQL, than to PostgreSQL.

In case, though, you expect some inter-galaxian business, then you have to think of the fact that each fiscal year the closed orders may be archived. Those old and served orders may be copied to another table (even a NoSQL DB), in another location, compressed and possibly in lower performance hardware, alleviating your production tables from some load. After years of usage (in a stable, not-expanding business), the Orders table will be rather stable: As many new orders per year, that many archived at the end of the year. 
In such a case, anyway, you can ask the aliens to give an alien machine to handle the DB.

Comment: Think big, man! Found in a contest's small print: "Notwithstanding the privacy statement and policy, if selected as a prizewinner, each prizewinner agrees, except where prohibited, to grant Sponsor and their parent companies, subsidiaries, affiliates, licensees and agents to use his/her name, entry contents, visual and audio likeness, biographical data and statements for any purpose, including but not limited to any commercial or publicity purpose, in perpetuity and throughout the universe, in any and all media now known or hereafter devised, without additional compensation or consideration."

Comment: PS A response I got to that quote: [Conditions of ACME's Unconditional Guarantee](http://www.kleinbottle.com/guarantee.htm).

Comment: One does not need to keep all these data in a single table, let alone a table at all! Today, such data are kept in some NOSQL implementations, that, again, can handle huge amounts without sweating. Again, one should not expect such entities to run on simple, low-end or cheap machines. 
"Think big" means also "pay big" . As the Spanish say "pay and even the Saints dance" .

Comment: Hi. I am not sure who your comment is directed to or what your point is. Maybe you want to add it to your answer?--Then click on "edit". Clarify via edits, not comments. My comments were just trying to jokingly agree with your rhetorical hyperbolic jump to the inter-galactic--"throughout the universe".

Answer (score 0):

As said by others, there is unlikely to be a requirement to archive as DBs are very capable.

One area not mentioned (and it varies by DB) is partitioning.  As its name suggests, partitioning allows you to manage chunks of data via the database rather than your code. While it can be used for performance, that is not the only case.  More likely it's used for administration (e.g. only back up this week's data, index rebuilds etc.).  You will need to check the capabilities of your specific database to see if there are any benefits to be gained (but don't get sucked down the performance rabbit hole!!)